# Correct total for measure evaluate all rows

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to use a measure to find the total impact of a price change.

Currently, I have a table with the date, region, product quantity, and revenue.

I have measures that return YTD and PY YTD for both revenue and product quantity.

`AvePriceYTD = Rev YTD/ Q YTD` and `AvePricePYYTD = RevPYYTD/Q_PYYTD`

My final measure is `PE = (AvePriceYTD-AvePricePYYTD)*Q_PY`

When totaling the AvePriceYTD-AvePricePYYTD is correct but when multiplying Q_PY it gives a different result to the sum of the individual PE for each region.

I know that this involves the HasOneFilter to choose the total but not sure how to evaluate each region individually and then total. It is not possible to evaluate each row as this is monthly data and there are multiple rows per region.

Answer (score 0):

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Quick-Measures-Gallery/Measure-Totals-The-Final-Word/m-p/547907

This link explains the answer, I initially didn't realize that the _table and _value were actually mean to be typed and not replaced with your own text.